# Codimension inequality of prime ideal in a regular local ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

In Exercise 10.6 of Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra, there is the following statement (not required to prove):

$(*)$ If $P$ is a prime ideal in a regular local ring $R$ and if $R\to S$ is a map of Noetherian local rings, then $\operatorname{codim} PS\leq \operatorname{codim} P$.

Actually Serre (1957) proved the following statement, which generalizes $(*)$:

**Theorem.** If $P$ is a prime ideal in a regular ring, then the superheight  of $P$ is equal to $\operatorname{codim}P$.

The definition of superheight is:

**Definition.** Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. The *superheight* of $I$ is the supremum of $\operatorname{codim} \varphi(I)S$, where $\varphi:R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\varphi(I)S\neq S$.

However Serre's theorem uses quite complicated materials, so I am looking for a direct proof for $(*)$.

(I asked this in mathstack https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4428223 and in a comment I'm suggested to ask it here.)

Comment: I wasn't able to locate that theorem in Serre's book. Did Serre really prove this?

Comment: @user26857 In chapter 10 of Eisenbud's book, it is written that the theorem is proved in this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-37123-6, which is written in french so I also couldn't find the statement. On the other hand pp.3-4 of http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/swb2.pdf tells what tools were used in the proof of the theorem (very briefly).

Comment: @user302934 [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-04203-8) is a copy in English of the same book. The result mentioned in your post is a consequence of theorem 3 on page 110. If the map is onto, we can write $S=R/Q$ for some ideal $Q\in R$ and apply theorem 3.  The general case can be reduced to this case.

Comment: @user782932 How can reduce the general case to the case $R\to S$ is onto? This is the main point here.

Comment: @user26857 I am not sure how this works. I just tried to provide the relevant theorem in Serre's book. As in Hochster's note linked above, maybe some experts on the theory of the intersection of multiplicities can provide more details.

Comment: @user782932 As I've mentioned in a comment on M.SE, this can be done by using Cohen factorization, a non-trivial result of Avramov, Foxby and Herzog. However, I suggested the OP to ask the same question here with the hope of a simpler approach.